# Sidekiq Install - uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, redis, mongoid, sidekiq

I am trying to integrate Sidekiq with my Rails Mongoid app.  I have been following the steps as outlined [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq?view=asciicast)

I also have redis & mongodb running locally.  However after I run bundle then when I try to start my server I get this error....

```
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.17.7/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:4:in `hook_rails!': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base (NameError)
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.17.7/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:16:in `block in <class:Rails>'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from C:/Users/example/Documents/Workspace/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

My environment.rb file is as follows...

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
App::Application.initialize!
```

I previously had resque with redis working with mongoid in this app, so its a sidekiq issue.  I don't have a database.yml file since I am using mongoid.  I also added the steps for kiqstand but I am getting the same error.  Unsure how to resolve?

Edit: I'm 90% sure its because Sidekiq is looking for ActiveRecord, however I removed ActiveRecord cause I'm using Mongo instead.  My application.rb has...

```
# remove activerecord and run off of mongo only
#require 'rails/all'
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/9327651/1026266
%w(
  action_controller
  action_mailer
  active_resource
  rails/test_unit
  sprockets
).each do |framework|
  begin
    require "#{framework}/railtie"
  rescue LoadError
  end
end
```

Now I just need to figure out how to tell sidekiq to not look for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lack of ActiveRecord was the issue, looks like there was a pull request - https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/pull/1090

But that was rejected, so I just had to add ActiveRecord to my app and add a dummy database.yml file.